# Istio Init Containers do not work with Pod Security Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks, istio-sidecar

I am running AWS EKS 1.16 with Istio Service Mesh 1.8.6. I have applied a Pod Security Policy where I am denying Privileged Containers, Running as Root and Privilege Escalation and am allowing NET_RAW and NET_ADMIN capabilities as Istio init containers need them.

But Istio_init containers run as root (UID 0) and thus fail validating against PSP. I tried changing the UID of the init containers within the Istio configmap for sidecar-injector but the istio-init container fails stating it could not get iptables.

So I am assuming istio_init definitely needs to run as root ?

How can make Istio_init containers run as non-root?

I tried enabling Istio CNI but that messes up my EKS implementation. The worker nodes immediately get marked as unhealthy so I had to disable Istio CNI and install AWS VPC CNI.

Any suggestions/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ik don't think it's possible without Istio CNI plugin : https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/#pod-requirements

Comment: I would ask this question to Istio team; on github.

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing istio? With the IstioOperator, you can set the  `values.global.proxy.privileged=false` to have non-privileged sidecars/init containers.
Concerning running with a non-root user, I'm not sure it's possible for the `istio-init` container: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23705 (uness you try out that istio CNI plugin, as already suggested).

Comment: Hey @Mark, I am not concerned about privileged container as I have disabled it. The issue is with the container running as root user (uid - 0). Not sure how I can disable that. I am installing Istio using istioctl and have exported the istio-sidecar-injector configmap from the istio-system namespace and edited that to test the security settings.

Comment: I'm afraid that with that setup it is not possible to use a non-root user (as already suggested by other people)